# Как сохранить виджет в нужном размере, в формате "*.jpeg"?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, grab, qpixmap

Как по нажатию кнопки сохранить изображение (`QPixmap`), но только не то что на экране, а его увеличенную версию.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(511,418)
        label=QLabel(self)
        label.setPixmap(QPixmap('imgonline-com-ua-Resize-0yi5po7h08mb1g.jpg'))
        label.setGeometry(120,50,281,271)

        save_photo= QPushButton('Сохранить фото', self)
        save_photo.setGeometry(30, 370, 93, 28)
        save_photo.setFont(QFont("Bahnschrift SemiLight SemiConde", 5))
        save_photo.clicked.connect(self.Save_Photo)

    def Save_Photo(self):
        pass

        #здесь функция сохранения фото
        # фото для сохранения : '2234719f-7737-4118-9ec3-6dfa0a6a26a7.jpeg'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_window = Window()
    my_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update**:

Под словом "увеличенная версия" я имею ввиду то, что
у человека на экране изображено фото, которое очень сжато в размерах,
оно очень маленькое и если его сохранить, то пользователь мало что увидит.

И чтобы пользователю было комфортно смотреть на фото у меня есть это же фото, но большего размера.

И в данном случае у меня не получается написать функцию для сохранения изображения.

Я пробовала метод `save()`.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не очень понятный. Объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается. Что значит: "увеличенную версию"? У вас есть изображение `imgonline-com-ua-Resize-0yi5po7h08mb1g.jpg`, которое вы поместили в `label` , подрезали изображение `label.setGeometry(120, 50, 281, 271)`, а теперь хотите получить это же полное изображение или что? Да и покажите что вы уже успели попробовать писать в методе `Save_Photo()`.

Comment: Под словом "увеличенная версия" я имею ввиду ,то что у человека на экране изображено фото которое очень сжато в размерах,оно очень маленькое и если его сохранить,то пользователь мало что увидит.И что бы пользователю было комфортно смотреть на фото у меня есть это же фото,но большего размера.И в данном случае у меня не получается написать функцию для сохранения фото.Я пробовала метод .save()

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, вы плохо объясняете задачу и проблему, которая у вас возникает. 
Сжато в размерах - это как? и почему фото сжато?
Вы должны приложить код, который демонстрирует эту проблему
и прикрепить изображение, которое, как вы говорите, большего размера.

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то приложение
может выглядеть, примерно так.

> QPixmap QWidget::[**grab**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#grab)(const QRect &rectangle = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(-1, -1)))
>
> Преобразует виджет в растровое изображение,
> ограниченное заданным прямоугольником.
> Если у виджета есть дочерние элементы, то они также прорисовываются
> в соответствующих позициях.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('lena.jpg')                               # +       
#        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('lena.jpg'))
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(100, 100))              # +
        self.label.setGeometry(120, 50, 281, 271)
        
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)                         # +++
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #105652;")          # +++
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #775652;")                # +++
         
        button_save_photo= QPushButton('Сохранить фото', self)
        button_save_photo.setGeometry(30, 370, 93, 28)
        button_save_photo.setFont(QFont("Bahnschrift SemiLight SemiConde", 7))
        button_save_photo.clicked.connect(self.save_photo)
        button_save_photo.setStyleSheet("background-color: #7799dd;")

# !!! vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def save_photo(self):
        #здесь функция сохранения фото
        # фото для сохранения : '2234719f-7737-4118-9ec3-6dfa0a6a26a7.jpeg'
        
        label = QLabel()
        label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        print(f'self.pixmap.size = {self.pixmap.size()}') 
        
        image = label.grab()
        image.save('2234719f-7737-4118-9ec3-6dfa0a6a26a7.jpeg')
        label.deleteLater()

        self.label_new = QLabel()        
        self.label_new.setPixmap(
            QPixmap('2234719f-7737-4118-9ec3-6dfa0a6a26a7.jpeg'))
        self.label_new.show()
# !!! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_window = Window()
    my_window.resize(511, 418)
    my_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**lena.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ДарьяШипунова что не так?